# JSON array to List of objects: UnrecognizedPropertyException

Tags: java, json, jackson

I couldn't find where I was wrong for the following array json string. I am not sure whether I am mapping right. I hope a friend will help me.

Thanks...

JSON string value is like below;

```
[
 {
  "PaymentRequest": {
    "RequestGuid": 123
     ...
    }
  },{
  "PaymentRequest": {
    "RequestGuid": 456
     ...
    }
} 
]
```

Object definition is like below;

```
@JsonRootName(value = "PaymentRequest")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class PaymentRequest{
@JsonProperty("RequestGuid")
String requestGuid; 
... 
}
```

My wrapper class is like below;

```
public class MyWrapper{
PaymentRequest paymentRequest;
//setter getter
}
```

My implementation is like below.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<MyWrapper> users = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<MyWrapper>>() {});
```

Result:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "PaymentRequest" (class vpos.dto.MyWrapper), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "paymentRequest"])
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 3, column: 24] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->vpos.dto.MyWrapper["PaymentRequest"])

Comment: in class MyWrapper it should be List<PaymentRequest> instead of PaymentRequest

Comment: What is `QNBWrapper`? Is that related to `MyWrapper` or is it the same and just a typo? If so then you'll probably want to add `@JsonProperty("PaymentRequest")`  to  `PaymentRequest paymentRequest;` (and remove that `@JsonRootName(value = "PaymentRequest")` - although I'm not familiar with that annotation so I might be wrong here).

Comment: I tried  "List<PaymentRequest>  PaymentRequest" and "List<PaymentRequest>  paymentRequests" , but i got same error.

Comment: Thanks brohers,  i changed it like this: and it works now. thank so much. @JsonProperty("PaymentRequest")
private PaymentRequest paymentRequest;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that property in json is called `PaymentRequest` and your field is `paymentRequest` with lower p at the begining. You can add annotation `@JsonProperty("PaymentRequest")` to your field or change property naming strategy like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE);
```